# Intuition behind defining closeness using sets in topology

Tags: general-topology

In [Wikipedia article about open set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_set), under the "motivation" sections, it says:

> In the set of all real numbers, one has the natural Euclidean metric; that is, a function which measures the distance between two real numbers: d(x, y) = |x - y|. Therefore, given a real number x, one can speak of the set of all points close to that real number; that is, within ε of x. In essence, points within ε of x approximate x to an accuracy of degree ε. Note that ε > 0 always but as ε becomes smaller and smaller, one obtains points that approximate x to a higher and higher degree of accuracy. For example, if x = 0 and ε = 1, the points within ε of x are precisely the points of the interval (-1, 1); that is, the set of all real numbers between -1 and 1. However, with ε = 0.5, the points within ε of x are precisely the points of (-0.5, 0.5). Clearly, these points approximate x to a greater degree of accuracy than when ε = 1.

And then it states that:

> The previous discussion shows, for the case x = 0, that one may approximate x to higher and higher degrees of accuracy by defining ε to be smaller and smaller. In particular, sets of the form (-ε, ε) give us a lot of information about points close to x = 0. **Thus, rather than speaking of a concrete Euclidean metric, one may use sets to describe points close to x.** This innovative idea has far-reaching consequences; in particular, by defining different collections of sets containing 0 (distinct from the sets (-ε, ε)), one may find different results regarding the distance between 0 and other real numbers. For example, if we were to define R as the only such set for "measuring distance", all points are close to 0 since there is only one possible degree of accuracy one may achieve in approximating 0: being a member of R. Thus, we find that in some sense, every real number is distance 0 away from 0. It may help in this case to think of the measure as being a binary condition, all things in R are equally close to 0, while any item that is not in R is not close to 0.

If we consider finite discrete set rather than $R$, and by this I mean something like following example:

Let $X=\{a,b,c,d\}$ and the topology $\tau = \{\phi, c ,\{a,b\},\{c,d\},\{a,b,c\},X\}$

Then here are the questions I have:

1. As it has been stated in bold font, we can use set to describe closeness, so what would define how close a hypothetical point $b$ is to a point $a$? Is it the number of sets they both appear against the number of sets $a$ appears alone without $b$? Does the size of the sets they both appear in have effect on this measure?
2. In the beginning of the second paragraph above it is stated that the smaller the (-ε, ε) interval is, the more accurate it defines ε, and contains more information about it. Again can you please describe the intuition about this observation on discrete set example (and not $R$)?

Comment: You can find some discussion of these issues in other questions, for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3439540/linking-the-intuition-of-topology-with-its-axiomatic-definition/3439663#3439663 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1598409/how-to-get-intuition-in-topology-concerning-the-definitions.

Answer (score 2):

The actual elements of the topology, or of a basis of the topology, are what tell you the meaning of "close". In the example of your second yellow box, for a given value of $\epsilon$ the set $(-\epsilon,+\epsilon)$ is a basis element containing $0$, and it tells a notion of being "close to $0$". The actual elements of the set $(-\epsilon,+\epsilon)$, such as $\epsilon/2$ or $-\epsilon/10$, are all judged as being "close to $0$" from the point of view of that set. Of course, different values of $\epsilon$ give you different notions of being "close to $0$".

In your example, the open set $\{a,b,c\} \in \tau$ gives you a notion of being "close to $a$"; the actual elements of that set, such as $b$ and $c$, are all judged as being "close to $a$". Of course, the set $\{a,b\} \in \tau$ gives you a different notion of being "close to $a$".

Comment: Thanks, and part of my question is how those two sets ${alb,c}$ and ${alb}$ are going to be taken into account when we talk about how close $b$ is to $a$? Are they two different unrelated notions? Are we taking some sort of average or something? And lets assume we had ${a,b,c}$ and ${a,b,c,d}$. Would that mean that $b$ is closer to $a$ in the first set since it is a smaller one?

Comment: You're adding too much meaning to the concept. Each individual element of the topology represents a different concept of closeness. There's no "averages", and there's no "closer". There are rules about how these different concepts of closeness are all related to each other, and those rules are contained in [the definition of a topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology#Topologies_on_sets). I suggest that, besides learning as much as you can about topological spaces, you also read some of the linked questions in my comment above.

Comment: Sure, I'll follow your suggestion. But can you tell me what is the difference between the notion of $b$ being close to $a$ in $\{a,b,c\} \in \tau$ and $\{a,b\} \in \tau$ as you have mentioned in your answer?

Comment: I'll repeat my earlier sentence: each individual element of the topology represents a different concept of closeness. So, $\{a,b,c\} \in \tau$ and $\{a,b\} \in \tau$ agree on whether $a$ and $b$ are close, although they disagree on whether $a$ and $c$ are close.