# Topology and closeness

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples, self-learning

I'm just starting self-learning Topology, and I have a lot of doubts...

Consider a set $X$ (*e.g.* the real numbers), and an open subset $S \subseteq X$. Let $\tau = \{ X, \varnothing, S \}$ be a topology on $X$.

Reading [this](http://www.goodmath.org/blog/2010/08/19/an-introduction-to-topology/) blog, it is stated that closeness of points of $S$ is assured by "[..]*that infinite ability to get take narrower and narrower subsets around a point*[..]".

But isn't closeness of points in $S$ just assured from the enunciation of $\tau$? Aren't we creating a *different* topology on $X$ by introducing those "narrower subsets"?

Comment: What do you mean by "closeness"?  If you meant "nearness" then, many topologies have no notion of distance.  Did you mean to write "closedness"?  But of course there are topologies in which points are not closed, so what are you asking?

Comment: @lulu I do know it is an improper use, but I am using the same notion of "closeness" from the blog article (or from this math.stackexchange answer, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3484735/277873

Comment: Questions should be self-contained.  You should not ask your readers to go read some other materials to learn critical definitions.  More broadly, using a familiar term to mean something non-standard is guaranteed to cause confusion.

Comment: @lulu having found the same lemma in two different contributes (and many more across the web) as a newbie in topology I thought that, even if not standard, its meaning was directly understandable - and so the question

Comment: Introducing topology intuitively to a potentially mixed audience, i.e. not ones who have necessarily done analysis beyond calculus, is not an easy thing to do. Personally, I don't think this blog post does it particularly well. My advice would be not to get too hung up on the specifics of the explanation, especially since it's designed to be a little hand-wavy. Maybe try looking at specific definitions of topology, and come back to it?

Comment: I don't see any Lemma here. Again, you appear to be assuming that we are all reading the same blog you are.   I'm with @TheoBendit .  Blogs are not a good place to learn math.

Comment: @TheoBendit thank you for your insight. Starting from ordinary and basic definitions of "topology" (e.g. Wikipedia&c.), the blog post was very confusing

Comment: @LoScrondo Sure. What I meant to say is, start studying from a rigorous perspective, and come back once you've got a feel for it. I would wait until you start encountering definitions like continuity at a point, or the limit of sequences, before you come back to something like this. Essentially, this is the one sentence selling point for topology: it's basically the least assumptions necessary to reasonably do analysis.

Comment: @lulu lemma is a polysemic term. As a novice I could not know if an informal, even inappropriate, term is however used in the field or not (so I did not think that it would be necessary to read a blog page). If you have suggestions to edit the question (and so get an answer) feel free to speak!

Comment: Again, as it stands, your question is too vague to answer.  Maybe reading all the materials you propose would clarify things, maybe not, but I don't think anyone here is likely to do that.  Certainly, I'm not going to do that.  As a general point: "closeness" appears to be related to "distance" and that requires a metric, which topological spaces need not possess.  Perhaps you meant to specify "metric space" or even "the reals with the standard topology", I don't know.  But, really...trying to learn math from blogs is very unlikely to succeed.  Get a standard reference and study that instead.

Comment: @lulu I leave the question open, but I'll try to rephrase the question for another post. Thank you anyway for your interpretation attempts

Comment: Despite what I said, I took a look at the blog.  It doesn't make sense.  I'm not sure what the author is thinking of, but it's not what I'd call Topology.  Speaking loosely, I';d say that Topology was the study of properties of sets which are preserved under continuous deformations.  That is, without filling up holes or tearing new ones.  Clearly, many concepts there need to be defined and that's what a standard reference will do for you.  Avoid blogs, this one in particular.

Comment: @lulu thank you

Comment: Many many thanks for your thoughts @dfi6ju. In the end I deepened my knowledge by myslef and now I'm fairly confident with the subject. I admit that maybe my question was badly worded, even if not absurd at all, and not so much worse than others I've read here and there on math.SE. Anyway, I am grateful to whoever put an effort in answering to me

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, if you have good visual/spatial ability, then thinking about distances and closeness can be very helpful in assimilating topological definitions, and in proving results. Pictures can help guide you.

Topology often involves the abstraction of concepts that seem kind of obvious in familiar spaces, like $\mathbb R, \mathbb R^2$. For example, to me, an open set $U$ in $\mathbb R$ is a set such that, no matter where I am in $U$, I can always move around a little bit while staying within $U$. In topology, this kind of idea gets abstracted into the fact that for any $x \in U \in \tau \subseteq 2^X$, there is an open set $B$ such that $x \in B \subseteq U$.

However, it's very important to realize that in topology, strictly speaking, *there is no notion of distance or closeness*. Thinking about distances can be helpful for intuition and guidance, as mentioned, but you can never, ever write anything down about distances, or closeness, because those concepts don't exist in topology.

You might think of topology like a game, where you try to abstract away concepts that are kind of obvious in familiar spaces, and define them without ever using the concept of distance. A lot of it amounts to just set theory.

Two other things you might find helpful to keep in mind:

1. A lot of other mathematical spaces---metric spaces, normed vector spaces, manifolds...---are topological spaces, so topology is hiding in the background in a lot of places. This is part of the reason why it matters.
2. The definition of a topology is *so* abstract and loose that it permits all kind of weird topological spaces that don't make a lot of sense. In fact, [entire books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387903127) have been written about weird counterexamples in topology. Depending on your goals, you might find it better not to worry too much about these weird spaces. Learn a couple, know that they're out there, but don't worry about them too much.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "you can never, ever write anything down about distances, or closeness, because those concepts don't exist in topology"? It conflicts with all of the discussion of distance and closeness in my textbook. Surely you only mean to say that topological spaces are not guaranteed to come equipped with a notion of distance? You cannnot plausibly mean that topology, the field of mathematics, has nothing to say about the notions of distance and closeness, right?

Comment: @dfi6ju Topological spaces do not, inherently, have any notion of distance. Thinking about distances and closeness may be helpful in proving certain properties of topological spaces, but if you ever write down anything about distance regarding a topological space $(X, \tau)$, then you've probably messed up, because $(X, \tau)$ does not necessarily have a metric.